# How to auto reset wireless connection after Windows 7 hibernate

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, hibernate

My desktop PC has a working wireless connection. However, when I hibernate and then boot back into Windows 7 the connection is left in a broken state. I don't care about identifying the cause of this as I can always fix it by manually disconnecting and connecting again to my wireless network.

My question is - what is the easiest way for me to automate this disconnect/reconnect step so that it happens every time I boot up/log in? Ideally I would want to have a login script which slept for 30 seconds, detected the state of the wireless connection, and if it wasnt in the connected state the connection is disconnected and then connected.

Comment: Login scripts don't run after hibernating.

Comment: Is there anything which does get run after hibernation or would I need a script that ran all the time (e.g. every minute)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could think of has a one time setup.

1. Run PowerShell as Administrator.
2. Type `Set-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned`
3. Confirm that you accept this policy (it means it will not run unsigned scripts that were downloaded from the internet, but will run local scripts).

Open Notepad and paste this:

```
Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb Runas -ArgumentList '-command "$wifi = get-WMIObject -class win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "adapterTypeID=9";$wifi.disable();$wifi.enable();"'
```

Click File > Save as... and type a filename **in quotes** that has an extension of ps1. Save to your desktop. For example "Cycle WiFi.ps1" (but include the quotes).

Now whenever you have to reset your adapter just double-click the ps1 file, or single-click it if you place it in your Quick Launch.

To reset your Ethernet adapter as well, you could also do:

```
Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb Runas -ArgumentList '-command "$wifi = get-WMIObject -class win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "adapterTypeID=9";$wifi.disable();$wifi.enable();$ethernet = get-WMIObject -class win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "adapterTypeID=0";$ethernet.disable();$ethernet.enable();"'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Louis has a good workaround (totally stealing that framework for self-elevating) but if you want to actually fix the issue, I would start by updating your BIOS and then updating the network adapter drivers.